# Leetcode question Search Insert Position my c# answer is time limit exceeded and i dont know why

Tags: c#, binary-search

as title
my code like

```
public static int SearchInsert(int[] nums, int target)
    {
        int result = 0;
        var count = Math.Truncate((decimal)(nums.Length / 2));
        while (result == 0)
        {
            if (nums[(int)count] > target && target > nums[(int)count - 1])
            {
                result = (int)count - 1;
            }
            if (nums[(int)count] < target && target < nums[(int)count - 1])
            {
                result = (int)count + 1;
            }
            if (nums[(int)count] == target)
            {
                result = (int)count;
            }
            count = nums[(int)count] > target ? count-- : count++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

i need use binary search to answer this

i think my code Time complexity is O(nlog n)

so i am confuse why i submit my code and return status was Time Limit Exceeded

do my code is wrong?

Comment: That's an `O(N)` solution you have there. You are changing `count` by only 1 every iteration where you don't find the target. I suggest you look up some binary search algorithms online.

Comment: `count = count++` (or `count = count++`) doesn't actually change the value of `count`! Your code is probably looping infinitely!

Comment: Once you've fixed it, can you write up a detailed answer to your question and add it below. You can even accept your own answer as well!

Answer (score 0):

that's my final answer!

```
public static int SearchInsert(int[] nums, int target)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int right = nums.Length - 1;
        int left = 0;
        if (nums[0] > target)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (nums[right] < target)
        {
            return right + 1;
        }
        while (right != 0)
        {
            var middle = (right + left) / 2;
            if (nums[middle] == target)
            {
                result = middle;
                break;
            }
            if (nums[middle] >= target && middle != 0 && target >= nums[middle - 1])
            {
                if (target == nums[middle - 1])
                {
                    result = middle -1;
                }
                else {
                    result = middle;

                }
                break;
            }
            if (nums[middle] <= target && middle!= nums.Length -1 && target <= nums[middle + 1])
            {
                result = middle + 1;
                break;
            }
            if (nums[middle] < target)
            {
                left = middle;
            }
            else
            {
                right = middle;
            }
        }
        
        return result;
    }
```

Runtime: 87 ms, faster than 95.63% of C# online submissions for Search Insert Position.

Memory Usage: 39.5 MB, less than 7.19% of C# online submissions for Search Insert Position.

Comment: using to much memory so i will thinking how to refactory